# PL/SQL de Oracle -Errores al abrir una tabla y ejecutar

Tags: plsql

** No puedo seguir adelante con el curso y no entiendo como resolverlo. Espero me puedan ayudar. Muchas Gracias!!**

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLEADOS

 (
  ID           NUMBER(2),
  NOMBRE       NVARCHAR2(100),
  FECHANACI    DATE,
  SALARIO      NUMBER(8,2),
  ACTUALIZADO  DATE
 );


SET DEFINE OFF;

   Insert into EMPLEADOS
         (ID, NOMBRE, FECHANACI, SALARIO)
    Values
         (1, 'Tonya Vazquez', TO_DATE('06/01/1980 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 1200);
    Insert into EMPLEADOS
         (ID, NOMBRE, FECHANACI, SALARIO)
     Values
         (2, 'Mathews Robbins', TO_DATE('02/23/1985 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 690);
    Insert into EMPLEADOS
        (ID, NOMBRE, FECHANACI, SALARIO)
    Values
        (3, 'Walton Vincent', TO_DATE('05/22/1990 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 800);
    Insert into EMPLEADOS
         (ID, NOMBRE, FECHANACI, SALARIO)
    Values
         (4, 'Audra Wade', TO_DATE('09/09/1972 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 1500);
    Insert into EMPLEADOS
         (ID, NOMBRE, FECHANACI, SALARIO)
    Values
         (5, 'Susanne Moody', TO_DATE('10/05/1995 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 1100);
    Insert into EMPLEADOS
         (ID, NOMBRE, FECHANACI, SALARIO)
     Values
          (6, 'Stevenson Dickson', TO_DATE('11/05/1968 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 420);
    Insert into EMPLEADOS
        (ID, NOMBRE, FECHANACI, SALARIO)
    Values
        (7, 'Hinton Cooper', TO_DATE('12/26/1973 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 660);
    Insert into EMPLEADOS
        (ID, NOMBRE, FECHANACI, SALARIO)
    Values
         (8, 'Hahn Brown', TO_DATE('02/28/1989 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 725);
    Insert into EMPLEADOS
        (ID, NOMBRE, FECHANACI, SALARIO)
    Values
        (9, 'Bennett Brady', TO_DATE('05/31/1991 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 1200);
    Insert into EMPLEADOS
        (ID, NOMBRE, FECHANACI, SALARIO)
    Values
        (10, 'Mueller Jimenez', TO_DATE('05/28/1981 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 475);
    COMMIT; 
''''
```

**Los Errores que me tira**

**Error que empieza en la línea: 1 del comando :
CREATE TABLE EMPLEADOS

(
ID           NUMBER(2),
NOMBRE       NVARCHAR2(100),
FECHANACI    DATE,
SALARIO      NUMBER(8,2),
ACTUALIZADO  DATE
)
Informe de error -
ORA-00955: este nombre ya lo está utilizando otro objeto existente
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
*Cause:
*Action:

Error que empieza en la línea: 14 del comando :
Insert into EMPLEADOS
(ID, NOMBRE, FECHANACI, SALARIO)
Values
(1, 'Tonya Vazquez', TO_DATE('06/01/1980 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 1200)
Informe de error -
ORA-01950: no existen privilegios en tablespace 'USERS'

Error que empieza en la línea: 18 del comando :
Insert into EMPLEADOS
(ID, NOMBRE, FECHANACI, SALARIO)
Values
(2, 'Mathews Robbins', TO_DATE('02/23/1985 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 690)
Informe de error -
ORA-01950: no existen privilegios en tablespace 'USERS'

Error que empieza en la línea: 22 del comando :
Insert into EMPLEADOS
(ID, NOMBRE, FECHANACI, SALARIO)
Values
(3, 'Walton Vincent', TO_DATE('05/22/1990 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 800)
Informe de error -
ORA-01950: no existen privilegios en tablespace 'USERS'

Error que empieza en la línea: 26 del comando :
Insert into EMPLEADOS
(ID, NOMBRE, FECHANACI, SALARIO)
Values
(4, 'Audra Wade', TO_DATE('09/09/1972 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 1500)
Informe de error -
ORA-01950: no existen privilegios en tablespace 'USERS'

Error que empieza en la línea: 30 del comando :
Insert into EMPLEADOS
(ID, NOMBRE, FECHANACI, SALARIO)
Values
(5, 'Susanne Moody', TO_DATE('10/05/1995 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 1100)
Informe de error -
ORA-01950: no existen privilegios en tablespace 'USERS'

Error que empieza en la línea: 34 del comando :
Insert into EMPLEADOS
(ID, NOMBRE, FECHANACI, SALARIO)
Values
(6, 'Stevenson Dickson', TO_DATE('11/05/1968 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 420)
Informe de error -
ORA-01950: no existen privilegios en tablespace 'USERS'

Error que empieza en la línea: 38 del comando :
Insert into EMPLEADOS
(ID, NOMBRE, FECHANACI, SALARIO)
Values
(7, 'Hinton Cooper', TO_DATE('12/26/1973 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 660)
Informe de error -
ORA-01950: no existen privilegios en tablespace 'USERS'

Error que empieza en la línea: 42 del comando :
Insert into EMPLEADOS
(ID, NOMBRE, FECHANACI, SALARIO)
Values
(8, 'Hahn Brown', TO_DATE('02/28/1989 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 725)
Informe de error -
ORA-01950: no existen privilegios en tablespace 'USERS'

Error que empieza en la línea: 46 del comando :
Insert into EMPLEADOS
(ID, NOMBRE, FECHANACI, SALARIO)
Values
(9, 'Bennett Brady', TO_DATE('05/31/1991 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 1200)
Informe de error -
ORA-01950: no existen privilegios en tablespace 'USERS'

Error que empieza en la línea: 50 del comando :
Insert into EMPLEADOS
(ID, NOMBRE, FECHANACI, SALARIO)
Values
(10, 'Mueller Jimenez', TO_DATE('05/28/1981 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 475)
Informe de error -
ORA-01950: no existen privilegios en tablespace 'USERS'

Confirmación terminada.**

Comment: Ya intentaste crear la tabla Empleado y no te deja crearla de nuevo. Pero además, estás usando un usuario sin permisos para crear cosas en el tablespace por defecto que es USERS.

Comment: Gracias Alfabravo pero...Entiendo que la tabla ya estaba creada en el archivo q abrí o importe. Por otro lado nosé como estoy usando el usuario sin permiso...yo ya habia creado uno...ademas, si me podes ayudar en como edito los privilegios?. Gracias!